# tag a href 100% clickable

Tags: html, css

I want to make the clickable div, not just the text itself..., how make it?

```
<div class="body">
<div class="div1"><a href="#" class="block bckgnd1"><span>See more comments</span></div></a><div class="div2 bckgnd2">2 of 18</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46o08zxj/1/)

example... [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for. What you need to this is make your `div1` and `div2` as `inline-block` and give them `width` the way I have provided. Once that is done, all you need to do is make your `anchor` element `display: block` so that it spans the entire width of the `div`. See this below :

```css
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 83%;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12%;
}

a.block {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
<div class="div1"><a href="#" class="block bckgnd1"><span>See more comments</span></div></a><div class="div2 bckgnd2">2 of 18</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can accept your answer, grateful, though I had seen on facebook ... they use for a div float: left, and also to make 100% clickable they do not limit the width css style ...

Comment: @FábioZangirolami Well, there are several ways you can get this particular layout. You can make use of `display: inline-block` property or `float: left`/`float: right` property. Its a question of ease and maintainability. I think this is more easy to understand and maintain. I also need to mention that in case you use `floats`, you will need to make use of an additional `clear` property to clear the `floats`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<a>` tag around everywhere you want clickable.  In the code below, the `<a>` tag surrounds the entire `div` that you want clickable.

```
<div class="body">
<a href="#" class="block bckgnd1"><div class="div1"><span>See more comments</span></div></a><div class="div2 bckgnd2">2 of 18</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the a around the div.

```
<a href="url"><div>text</div></a>
```